publish a file in magnolia asset app not trigger
In the Magnolia asset app, I created a folder named Sample. Inside this folder, I uploaded PDF files, Word documents, and image files. However, when I publish these files, the webhook is not triggered. I am using Magnolia DX Core. The webhook only triggers when I publish content in the Pages, Tour, or Stories app.
Here is my webhook configuration:
name: webhook
url: "my webhook url"
method: POST
headers:
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
enabled: true

events:
  - name: goLive
    eventType: Published
  - name: outdated
    eventType: Unpublished


